# Using an Int as the database selection Argument

Tags: android, sql, database, int

I know this will seem like an obvious question, but i've yet to find an answer, so any help would be appreciated. I want to query a SQL database based on an int but all the examples and tutorials that i have found so far only let you query using String [], as the Args, i have tried to modify these to fit my situation but so far have failed. Here's the code i have so far.

```
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from subGoals where _id=?", 
            new Integer [] {getIntent().getIntExtra("goal", 999999)} );
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the String value of the int to pass in as an argument.

```
new String[]{String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("goal", 999999))}
```

Comment: I thought of that, however the data type of _id is an int, so would this still work? Will it compare _id as a String??

Comment: Everything you pass to SQLite is a String, then SQLite sorts it all out later. Don't worry, it's pretty clever.